# Examples required for operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Please can someone give me examples for following cases.

1) let $T $ be bounded compact operator in $l^2$ , and let $\sigma(T)$ be the spectrum of operator.

a) $\sigma(T)= [0,1]$

b) $\sigma(T)=\{0 \} \cup \{ z\in \Bbb C : |z|=1\} $

2) If $T$ is bounded non-compact operator in $l^2$ which has exactly two eigenvalues.

i only need examples ( explanation not necessary, based on operator i will try to work spectrum myself.)

I was able to come with examples in the case of compact normal operators with finite spectrum. Here i am struggling as the first case there is continuous spectrum and in the second it is non-compact.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Looking at the [spectral theorem for compact operators in a Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem), we get that the only possible accumulation point of the spectrum of a compact operator in $\ell^2$ is $0$, and hence there are **no compact operators** where the spectrum is contains an interval (1a) or the unit circle (1b).
2. Consider any orthogonal partition $V_1 \oplus V_2$ of $\ell^2$, and let $Tx = 1\cdot x_1 + 2\cdot x_2$ where $x=x_1 + x_2$ with $x_i \in V_i, I=1,2$.